# Get-WsusComputer and get Windows updatestatus

Tags: windows, powershell

how can I check the update status on wsus via powershell for one certian machine?
I found a script but this is for all computers in wsuws, how could I modify this to check one server only? This Information is later needed for a selfservice portal

```
# This script grabs WSUS information and outputs it to a HTML report.  Specifically, updates that are failed/needed and critical.
# File paths
$reportPath = $PSScriptRoot + "C:\script\report.html"
# Get date for timestamp
$date = Get-Date
# Retrieve WSUS server.  Change localhost to run from remote machine.
$server = Get-WsusServer -Name "localhost" -PortNumber 8530
# Grab critical updates that are failed or needed.
$critupdates = Get-WsusUpdate -UpdateServer $server -Status FailedOrNeeded -Classification Critical,security -Approval AnyExceptDeclined | Sort-Object -Descending -Property ComputersNeedingThisUpdate
# Create empty update array and loop through updates, grabbing info from update object in each row.
$updates = @()
foreach ($update in $critupdates) {
    $title = $update.Update.Title
    $id = $update.UpdateId
    $need = $update.ComputersNeedingThisUpdate
    $props = @{
        'Update Name'=$title;
        'Update ID'=$id;
        'Servers In Need'=$need;
    }
    $updobj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props
    $updates += $updobj
}
$updatesHtml = $updates | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent "<h2>Critical Updates</h2>"
# Create HTML file
$head = @"
    <title>Critical Updates</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        h1 {
            color: #1E87F0;
        }

        h2 {
            color: #1E87F0;
        }

        table {
            background-color: #1E87F0;
        }

        td {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            color: #666666;
            padding: 3px;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #1E87F0;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 3px;
        }
    </style>
"@


# Convert everything to HTML and output to file
ConvertTo-Html -Head $head -Body $updatesHtml | Out-File $reportPath
```

Or maybe a oneliner is possile? But this s not working as well

```
Get-WsusComputer  -NameIncludes "myservername" | Get-WsusUpdate -Classification All -Approval Unapproved -Status FailedOrNeeded
```

Comment: _"But this s not working as well"_ Can you elaborate? What happens? Error messages?

Comment: that is not intended, you can not pipe like get-computer | get-update or something like this, Or maybe it is possible but I have´nt found a solution yet. Actually I just want to get on computer and the update status with information like, missing updates, last synch, what kind of update is missing... stuff like this

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope = get-wsuscomputer;
 $wsus.GetComputerTargetByName($server.FullDomainName)
```

where $server.fulldomain is known of course, if no you can retrieve info about all servers as below:

```
foreach($server in $scope)
{
    $wsus.GetComputerTargetByName($server.FullDomainName)
}
```